# Delete multiple rows in django

Tags: django, datatable

I am trying to delete severals rows at the same time in django.

How can I simply change the state of the booleanfield 'to_delete', just by clicking on the checkbox?

I am using datatables. The way how I am doing it is to create a boolean to_delete in my model, when the checkbox is selected, I am calling the function delete_multiple_company in my view. However, this doesn`t work. Any idea, what I am doing wrong please. Many Thanks,

I`ve created my view:

**views.py**

```
def delete_multiple_company(request, company_id):
    company = get_object_or_404(Company, pk=company_id)
    company = Company.objects.get(pk=company_id)
    company.objects.filter(to_delete=True).delete()    
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("company:index_company"))
```

**urls.py**

```
 url(r'^(?P<company_id>[0-9]+)/delete_multiple_company/$', views.delete_multiple_company, name='delete_multiple_company'),
```

**models.py**

```
class Company(models.Model):
    to_delete = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

**index.html**

```
<a href="{% url 'company:delete_multiple_company' company.id %}" id="table" class="btn btn-default btn-sm active float: right" style="float: right;"><span class="fa fa-plus"></span>Delete Companies</a>

<table id="dtBasicExample" class="table table-striped table-hover">
     <thead>
        <tr>
           <th>Select</th>
           <th>#</th>
           <th>Checked ?</th> 
        </tr>
     </thead>
        <tbody>
           {% for company in companys.all %}
        <tr>
           <td id="{{ company.id }}"><input type="checkbox" class="companyCheckbox" name="checkedbox" id="{{ company.id }}" value="{{ company.id }}"></td>                              
           <td>{{ company.id }}</td>
           <td>{{ company.to_delete }}</td>
       </tr>
           {% endfor %}
                                 
        </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Just for your information, this is highly insecure. Somebody could just enter the url some ids and delete everything. You should check in your view if the creator is also the user requesting the url...

Comment: what does set company to_delete to True

Comment: Thank you hansTheFranz, I`ll check this. @iklinac, if the checkbox (1st column) is checked, the field to_delete is changed from False to True. Then, when we click on the Delete Multiples Rows button, this should delete all selected rows. I am using datatable and I can easily delete them from the table but it they will not be deleted from the database. I am open to any suggestions.

Comment: How can I simply change the state of the booleanfield 'to_delete', just by clicking on the checkbox?

Answer (score 0):

I experienced a similar issue as you, what I did was put in a form.

**index.py**

```
<form method="POST" class="post-form">{% csrf_token %} 
    <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default">Delete</button>
<span class="fa fa-plus"></span>Delete Companies</a>

<table id="dtBasicExample" class="table table-striped table-hover">
     <thead>
        <tr>
           <th>Select</th>
           <th>#</th>
           <th>Checked ?</th> 
        </tr>
     </thead>
        <tbody>
           {% for company in companys.all %}
        <tr>
           <td id="{{ company.id }}"><input type="checkbox" class="companyCheckbox" name="checkedbox" id="{{ company.id }}" value="{{ company.id }}"></td>                              
           <td>{{ company.id }}</td>
           <td>{{ company.to_delete }}</td>
       </tr>
           {% endfor %}
                                 
        </tbody>
</table>
<button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default">Delete</button>
</form>
```

Clicking on the button then triggered the POST method in my view.

**views.py**

```
def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print('I made it here')
        # Put your code here, note you will return a dict, so some trial and error should be expected
```